# Python as a first language?

Tags: learning, c, python

I have just started working in Information Security World. I want to learn the Python language for creating my own automated tool for Fuzzing, SQL-Injection etc.

My question is I don't know much about C language (only basic knowledge) but I want to learn directly Python Language so is it good?

I have seen there is lots of difference between Python and C (obviously) and for Information Security field Python = GOD so I want to know learning Python need any experience on C language? If not so can I start learning Python directly?

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/ may be of interest to you, OP. I'm not suggesting this question be moved there, simply a recommendation to aid him in his IT security travels.

Answer (score 5):

If you are interested in computer security, then having understanding of C and assembly is almost certainly a requirement(depending a bit on what kind of things you're interested in though). That said, I would personally begin with Python to learn basic concepts of programming but move onto C and assembly at some point to deepen understanding of how software *really* works at the operating system and hardware level.

Regarding security, **[There's also the IT Security StackExchange](http://security.stackexchange.com)**  site

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to know C if you want to learn Python. Do take a look around you what kind of language other people use, and find out why. If everyone else uses e.g. C it could make sense to use that. This makes collaboration and exchange of code easier. In addition, there might be reasons to choose a certain language, e.g. libraries or performance issues. I don't know what your situation is, but Python is great language imo.